# Applying opacity on hover only when the image is linked

Tags: css

I'm using weebly to host a site -- on my about page, I have several images. Some of the images are linked, some are not. I'd like the images that are links to have opacity when you hover over them, and I achieved this by:

```
.wsite-page-about .wsite-multicol-col img:hover{
opacity: 0.70;
transition: all 0.3s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

But this makes all the images gain the opacity upon hover. How can I make this only apply when the image is linked?

Comment: Are you using `a` tag to link the images?

Comment: @SuperCoolHandsomeGelBoy yup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an `a` to the front of your CSS to select images that are a child of an `<a>`.  Something like:

```css
.wsite-page-about .wsite-multicol-col a img:hover {
  opacity: 0.70;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
img {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wsite-page-about">
  <div class="wsite-multicol-col">
    <a href="#hovered"><img src="http://www.hover.com/assets/home/og_hover-ecd9c237693419342687076277876b71ed0868105bbe3bc321ec844af7bbd38d.png"/></a>
    <br />
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1d/A_LAKE_A_LANE_A_LINE_A_LONE_-_bpNichol.jpg/800px-A_LAKE_A_LANE_A_LINE_A_LONE_-_bpNichol.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hm. this is still making my images w/o hyperlinks opaque on hover

Comment: Post edited with snippit created, the concept is demonstrated correct. You may have some other CSS creating the effect for you. Try using your we browser's inspector to see if other rules are applied to image elements and/or removing this type of rule entirely.

Answer (score 0):

If your image looks something like this, (i.e.) inside  tag then applied opacity on hover should work.

HTML

```
   <a href = "#"><img src = "img.jpg" /></a>
```

CSS

```
a > img:hover{
opacity:0.70;
transition: 0.6s ease;
-webkit-transition: 0.6s ease;
-moz-transition: 0.6s ease;
-ms-transition: 0.6s ease;
-o-transition: 0.6s ease;
}
```